# API da sigep retorna array com visibilidade das propriedades

Tags: php

Estou utilizando uma [API da Sigep](https://github.com/stavarengo/php-sigep) que encontrei no github, fiz alguns testes e deu certo, o problema é que gostaria de retornar os resultados em JSON ou XML, e o retorno da classe está vindo com a visibilidade de suas propriedades, já percebi isso em outras bibliotecas/libraries, isso é algum tipo de padrão?

O exemplo usado foi o **"calcPrecoPrazo"**, dentro da pasta exemplos/calcPrecoPrazo.php

exemplo de retorno:

```
Array
(
    [*isSoapFault] => 
    [*errorCode] => 
    [*errorMsg] => 
    [*result] => Array
        (
            [0] => PhpSigep\Model\CalcPrecoPrazoResposta Object
                (
                    [servico:protected] => PhpSigep\Model\ServicoDePostagem Object
                        (
                            [codigo:protected] => 41068
                            [idServico:protected] => 109819
                            [nome:protected] => Pac 41068
                            [_failIfAtributeNotExiste:protected] => 1
                        )

                    [valor:protected] => 15.79
                    [prazoEntrega:protected] => 5
                    [valorMaoPropria:protected] => 0
                    [valorAvisoRecebimento:protected] => 0
                    [valorValorDeclarado:protected] => 0
                    [entregaDomiciliar:protected] => 1
                    [entregaSabado:protected] => 
                    [erroCodigo:protected] => 0
                    [erroMsg:protected] => 
                    [_failIfAtributeNotExiste:protected] => 1
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ele não está retornando o objeto com suas propriedades. Ele está retornando um valor que pode ser *txt*, *json*, *xml* etc.

Porém o código deles converte esse resultado para o objeto `PhpSigep\Model\CalcPrecoPrazoResposta` e utiliza o `var_dump` **apenas** para demonstrar o resultado.

Para você acessar os dados desse objeto em seu site, de forma "correta", basta invocar algum método com o prefixo `get`. Ex:

```
<?php

if (isset($response["result"]) && is_array($response["result"])) {
    foreach($response["result"] as $result) {
        echo sprintf("Serviço: %s <br>", $result->getServico());
        echo sprintf("Serviço: %s <br><br>", $result->getValor());
    }
}
```